# Double error in Web.config file ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, machine.config

So when I publish my application I these following errors which I do not get in local mode.

> "System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed."

So it is said that I'm supposed to write the following code in my Web.config to solve this first error:

```
<trustLevel name="Full">
```

So I did, but then, I got this error:

> "This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the site administrator has locked access to this section using
>   from an inherited configuration file."

It apparently has to do with the machine.config (which I cannot find)...

Does anyone have a proper solution for this?

If you wish to test it yourselves, here is the URL:

http://wideart.se/Exhibition

Regards

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party hosting company, or you do you have full access to the server the website is running on in production?

Comment: Yes im usiing a 3rd party hosting company. But the strange thing is that the other URL's works just fine. My home, contact etc...

Comment: The host probably wants your app to run in medium trust. The way to get around it is to fix the component that is demanding higher trust than allowed. Is there a stack trace accompanying the error to figure out where the problem is?

Comment: I tested all the levels of trust, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What is around `<trustLevel name="Full">` ?
Is it inside `system.web`?

Try

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

Comment: I get " This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file." after doing this.